# Is there any literature that systematically analyzes current quantum chemistry algorithms using Big O notation for time and memory cost?

Tags: reference-request, molecular-modeling, computational-chemistry, algorithms

Big O notation is commonly seen in the papers on novel computational methods. However, only a few of them include rigorous analysis of the algorithm. Is there any literature that summarizes current prevalent computational chemistry algorithm of density functional theory, coupled cluster, density matrix renormalization group and quantum monte carlo and gives analysis of their big O notations?

Comment: DFT costs $N^3$, CC cost depends on the order of the CC expansion, but is easy to find, and the cost of DMRG  is summarized in section 4.6 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2040.pdf). In each of these cases, the cost analysis is maybe enough for an end-of-term project for a senior-level undergrad course, but is not enough to justify publication in a scientific journal. Your use of the word "*etc.*" also makes this question very open-ended. Perhaps you should ask for the cost of the specific algorithms you're interested in, because there likely is no paper that has what you want.

Comment: @NikeDattani  I agree this is a very open question. However, I think this problem is non-trival. For example the statement that DFT is O(N^3) is imprudent. I think the details matters. There are many variation or ramification of the same method. Like in DFT, there are many tricks on diagonalizatin and constructions for integrals. I think people should be more systematic or even build a data base that classify and summarize each algorithm.

Comment: Your question said DFT, not "all possible variants of DFT such as linear-scaling DFT". Does a database of the costs of every quantum chemistry algorithm and implementation exist? I do not think so. Therefore I worry there may never be an answer. Is it possible to make the question more specific?

Comment: I have specified the question a little. I hope this would work.

Comment: I think this is a great question. In fact, this comment chain demonstrates that. Addressing @Nike Dattani's comment, rarely in practice does DFT actually scale as $N^3$. A great answer is discussed [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/how-does-density-functional-theory-scale-with-system-size). I agree that it would be nice to see similar analysis/discussion but with actual references and/or analysis to back it up.

Comment: I admit I do not know much about DFT. For coupled cluster the cost of CCSD is $\mathcal{O}(N_eN_v^5)$, for CCSDT: $\mathcal{O}(N_e^2N_v^6)$, for CCSDTQ: $\mathcal{O}(N_e^3N_v^6)$, for CCSDTQP: $\mathcal{O}(N_e^4N_v^7)$ and you can quickly see the pattern. For DMRG, section 4.6 of the paper I referenced in my first comment, answers the same types of questions as Andrew's link does for DFT. For QMC you do have to be specific whether you mean FCIQMC, FN-DMC, AFQMC, VMC, PIMC etc. The issue with this question is that the answer is most likely "no", which means we won't see an answer.

Comment: It would be fun to answer this for the implementations not just the algorithms. Prefactors matter and different formalisms of the same method can have noticeably different costs.

Comment: I think one point people normally ignore when considering the time scaling is how many recursive call is required to get converged result. Consider for a DFT calculation, without any pre-knowledge for the system, people do not know how many iteration required to get converged result. To a extreme case, if number of iteration is infinite then the running time is infinite. I think CC residue equation is solved in a similar manner. I think this issue brings some uncertainty for ab-initio methods.